# Rotating & Scaling

Tags: transforms

How can I rotate something without having to roll the mouse around the screen? Can I change the rotate to work with simple up/down or left/right movement?

How can I scale something on 2 axes in the ortho view simultaneously without using the "Constraint Axis" checkboxes after the scale operation. Now I've had to do that, or scale it in one axis first, and then the other. I tried using the little circle in the center of the manipulator thing, but it was scaling in 3 axes.

Also.. how can I get the scale to work with simple up/down or left/right movement? Scaling gets weird when the mouse cursor is close to the center of the scaled things, so far I've never needed the negative scaling...

---

edit: Trying to clarify the simpler rotation & scale.

Rotation: Activate rotation with the manipulator or the shortcut. Move mouse right for positive rotation. Move mouse left for negative rotation. Is it possible to change rotation to function like this?

Scale: Activate the scaling. Move mouse up for increase in the scale. Move mouse down for decrease in the scale. Is it possible to change scale to function like this?

Comment: This is slightly hard to understand what you're talking about. Could you add some screen shots to explain it better?

Comment: The stack exchange format works best when just 1 question is asked at a time, might be better if you could ask them separately.

Comment: Basically the same question. SixthOfFour answered nicely.

Answer (score 7):

You can rotate, scale and translate by using the arrow keys or by typing a number, e.g. <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> will move the selected object(s) 1.4 BU along the X axis.
You can also use the minus sign with the numbers. The above combination would move the object(s) to right when in front view, and <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> would move it/them to the left. <kbd>-</kbd> acts as a toggle, so pressing it multiple times will alternate between positive and negative direction. It can be toggled at any time during the number input, so
<kbd>G</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>
<kbd>G</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>
and even
<kbd>G</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>
are all equivalent

Transforming along two axes is done by excluding the third axis with the shift key, e.g. <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> will exclude the Z axis, thus scaling along the X and Y axes.