# Rotating in the 3D-View using a linear mouse pointer displacement?

Tags: 3d-view, customization, mouse

To apply some rotation to an object or an element, the usual method is to turn around the rotation center:

[image]

This means one have to look at the current position of the mouse cursor in order to know if the mouse must be moved up, down, left or right. My personal feeling is this is not easy to use:

- The distance of the pointer from the center controls the increment/decrement, it is difficult to maintain the same rate.
- When using "Continuous grab" (default) and the pointer has wrapped around the screen, the direction to use becomes unclear.

Is there an option to use a linear displacement to control the amount of rotation, e.g. move up to increase rotation, move down to decrease rotation?

I'm not asking how to use numeric input (mentioned in [How can I rotate something without having to roll the mouse around the screen?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19537/rotating-scaling)) or the transformation manipulator ("gizmo").